# $A$ and $B$ are symmetric across the diagonal (because $4=4$). Find their triple factorizations $LDU$ and say how $U$ is related to $L$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm following the MIT OCW Introduction to Linear Algebra Course. This problem is problem $12$ from section $2.6$ in Introduction to Linear Algebra, Fourth Edition by Gilbert Strang. The lecture for this section on MIT OCW is of terrible quality, so I am a bit lost in understanding $LU$ and $LDU$ factorization.

Here is the problem:

$A$ and $B$ are symmetric across the diagonal (because $4=4$). Find their triple factorizations $LDU$ and say how $U$ is related to $L$ for these symmetric matrices:

**Symmetric** $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 4 & 11 \end{bmatrix}\quad B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 4 & 12 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

What I have so far:

$${ E }_{ 21 }A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 4 & 11 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=U\quad $$

$$A={ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }U=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=LDU$$

So, I found $L$, which is ${ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. I also found my $U$, which is $U=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

I can see a similarity between them, but I do not know how to express it mathematically.

When it comes to matrix $B$, I find myself to be confused about what to do at a certain point. This is what I have thus far:

$${ E }_{ 21 }B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 4 & 12 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So, now I see a situation in which I should probably do a row exchange, namely between row 2 and row 3. However, the textbook saids something about how $A=LU$ is 
elimination without row exchanges, so I'm confused as to what I should be doing here.

This is what I continued doing:

$${ P }_{ 23 }({ E }_{ 21 }B)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ E }_{ 32 }\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=U$$

So, I got this $U$, but it seems to differ from the $U$ shown in the solution in the back of the book.

So, I would like to know how I could express the relation between $U$ and $L$ in the triple factorization for matrix $A$. I would also like to know what I am doing wrong in trying to find the $LDU$ factorization for matrix $B$. Hints are much better appreciated than direct answers.

Comment: As a starter of sorts: did you try getting the plain (that is, unpivoted) $LU$ decomposition dirst?

Comment: @J.M. For Matrix B?

Comment: Well, whatever matrix you're taking the $LDU$ decomposition of. One check is to start with the $LU$ decomposition and then derive $LDU$ from there.

Comment: @J.M. If you haven't noticed, that is what I have done for matrix $A$. $$A={ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }U=LU=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=LDU$$

I found $LU$, and then I divided each row of $U$ by its first nonzero entry (the pivot). The pivots $2$ and $3$ went into $D$.

Comment: Very good. Now see if any one matrix can be transposed into another.

Comment: @J.M. Ok, so I went on Khan Academy and watched the video about the transpose of a matrix. Then, I was able to come up with a solution for matrix $A$. So, this is my solution: $A={ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }U=LU=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=LDU$ and $U$ is related to $L$ by $U={ L }^{ T }$

Comment: In regards to matrix $B$, I realized that I could solve it without doing any row exchanges by just continuing after ${ E }_{ 21 }B$ 

So, ${ E }_{ 21 }B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 4 & 12 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Then, ${ E }_{ 32 }{ (E }_{ 21 }B)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=U$

Comment: Then I get $L$ by: ${ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }{ E }_{ 32 }^{ -1 }=L=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

So, now I can finally produce the final result: $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=LDU$ and $U$ is related to $L$ by $U={ L }^{ T }$


@J.M. Thank you for giving me that hint. I would like to give you your due credit, so please type it up as an answer below and I will accept it an +1.

Comment: I would prefer that you write your answer to your own question, since you did all the work. (I will upvote if you do so.) Now that you've done the legwork: look up the $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ factorization, and if you have time, Cholesky factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with matrix $A$:

$${ E }_{ 21 }A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 4 & 11 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=U\quad $$

Now, we can derive $LDU$ from $LU$:

$$A={ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }U=LU=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=LDU$$

So, we found $L$, which is ${ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. We also found $U$, which is $U=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. These two are related by $U={L}^{T}$

Now let's find the triple factorization, $LDU$ of matrix $B$:

$${ E }_{ 21 }B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 4 & 12 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ E }_{ 32 }{ (E }_{ 21 }B)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=U$$

Now we create a matrix $L$ from the inverses of ${ E }_{ 21 }$ and ${ E }_{ 32 }$

$${ E }_{ 21 }^{ -1 }{ E }_{ 32 }^{ -1 }=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=L$$

We can now put it all together to get:

$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=LU$$

Finally, we can derive $LDU$ from $LU$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=LDU$$

We can now see that our $L=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, is related to $U=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ by $U={L}^T$

Thank you to @J.M. for providing me with the hint/guidance that enabled me to find the solution to this problem.